# Как получить правильную форму множественного числа существительного?

Tags: алгоритм

Как получить правильную форму множественного числа существительного в моем случае?

```
pluralize_time = (current_time) ->
  current_time_modulo = current_time % 10
  if current_time_modulo >= 2 && current_time_modulo <= 4
    return "Просмотрено " + current_time + " секунды ролика"
  if current_time_modulo >= 5 && current_time_modulo <= 9 || current_time_modulo == 0
    return "Просмотрено " + current_time + " секунд ролика"
  if current_time_modulo == 1
    return "Просмотрена " + current_time + " секунда ролика"
```

Я получаю неправильные ответы в таких случаях:

```
Просмотрена 11 секунда ролика
Просмотрено 12 секунды ролика
Просмотрено 13 секунды ролика
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На js:

```
function plural(num, words) {
    var cases = [2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2];  
    return words[ (num % 100 > 4 && num % 100 < 20) ? 2 : cases[Math.min(num % 10, 5)] ];  
}

console.log(plural(2, ['секунда', 'секунды', 'секунд']));
```

[Смотреть](http://jsfiddle.net/po3k0ag0/)

Comment: а не могли бы объяснить

Comment: @helplz Что именно? Представленный выше алгоритм?

Comment:     (num%100 > 4 && num%100 < 20) ? 2

Из значений,которые дают остаток от деления в диапазоне от 5 до 19,выбирается 2-ой элемент массива `['секунда','секунды',**'секунд'**]` (не забываем,что отсчет индекса начинается с нуля),иначе:

    cases[Math.min(num%10, 5)]

Из значений,которые дают остаток от деления > 5,выбирается 5,либо сам остаток от деления (значения от 0 до 4) - выбирается минимальное из этих двух значений `Math.min()`.Данное значение является индексом "корректирующего" массива `cases`.Далее,полученное значение "корректирующего" массива является индексом исходного массива `words`

Comment: Кстати, можно в качестве входящих данный задать не слова, а лишь их окончания:

     console.log('секунд' + plural(2, ['а', 'ы', '']));

Comment: @romeo спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```
function word($num, $words) {
    $cases = array (2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2);  
    return $words[ ($num%100 > 4 && $num %100 < 20) ? 2 : $cases[min($num%10, 5)] ];  
}

echo word(11, array('секунда', 'секунды', 'секунд'));
```

Возможно, поможет.

Работает так: `word(11, array(' секунда', ' секунды', ' секунд'))`